# Can we store image in vuex? Should we do it?

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I am trying to store profile thumbnail for easy access. Since I want to minimize resource consumption by eliminating the methods to fetch the image path every time the user reloads the page. Can we store image data in vuex? If so, should we do it?

Comment: As base64 string? You likely have XY problem. Images are supposed to be cached by means of browser. Vuex isn't persistent by default, so it doesn't solve the problem with page reloads

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!

After the image response, pass the image to `URL.createObjectURL()` ([Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)). This will cache the image in the browser and will give you a local image url, which you can then re-use:

```
const imageUrl: string = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
if (imageUrl) {
     // Update your store with an object like this:
     { id: imageId, url: imageUrl };
}
```

Then you can search your `imageUrl[]` state, where you saved this, by the `id` and retrieve the URL again.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out...Much Appreciated

Comment: Not working for me like this... Tried a lot but didn't figure it out, and this is certainly not working without any additions...

Comment: You can post a question and I can take a look at it, but make sure to provide your code.